# AJAX not POST'ing in JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
I have the following to try and POST a JSON request to Google's URL Shortener

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url",
  data: { longUrl: "http://some.url" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    console.log( msg );
  });
```

This comes back as a 400 error because the request isn't formatted correctly. Looking at the request in fiddler, I can see it's like this;

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 29
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4

longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fsome.url
```

I can modify the request to the following, which works (excluding header);

```
{ longUrl=http://some.url }
```

So why is ajax not formatting the data as a JSON?

Comment: `{ longUrl=http://some.url }` isn't json either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery doesn't turn objects into JSON strings for you. `dataType` is for the response, and `contentType` is for the server's benefit. You still have to actually serialize the data to JSON:

```
$.ajax({
/* ... */
  data: JSON.stringify({ longUrl: "http://some.url" })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try: `JSON.stringify` ?

Something like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ longUrl: "http://some.url" })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass your json object as a string, your request will return ok for instance I got an object back with this url http://goo.gl/UXeQ.

See http://jsfiddle.net/3oy3c5tq/

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url",
  data: '{ longUrl: "http://some.url" }'
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    console.log( msg );
  });
```

Comment: Strictly speaking for it to be valid JSON you'd need to quote the `longUrl` as well.. `'{ "longUrl": "http://some.url" }'` - obviously google doesn't mind so much